# Downloading video using command line

Tags: video, download, wget

I use right click on a button and select `Download Linked File As` to download a video file into my computer.

[image]

I'd like to automatize it with scripts, so I opened the source code and copy the link and then use `youtube-dl,`wget`,`movgrab`and`curl -L -o` to download the file.

[image]

However, I can't download the files with error messages. The page link can be opened with web browser, so I think the link itself is OK.

[image]

Then, how can I download the video just like I do with right click and select?

Comment: You can use [FFmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/)`ffmpeg.exe" -i "URL GOES HERE" -c copy "Downloaded File.ts"` asssuming you have the link. if not, getting the link is a whole different thing. you'll need a browser plugin to pass the link to ffmpeg, or you'll need to find/build a webpage reader that can catch the link from the page source or the online player.

Comment: is this what you're looking for?